# Using Live Sass Compiler changed website completely and cannot revert back to regular CSS?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, frontend, styling

I was trying to add animations with SCSS and am fairly new to it and was trying to learn the differences between CSS and SCSS. I saw that there was a Live Sass Compiler that reads in the SCSS code and you can view those changes live. When I implemented the extension, my website completely changed and all of my CSS was removed from elements such as images, text, and text styling. I tried to revert back by removing the extension and all of the SCSS files that were added but the website is still not correct and everything is not proportional and the CSS seems to have been removed even though the file exists and the HTML file does link to it. Is there any way for me to go back to how my website style was before using the Sass Compiler? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using version control like github i think it isn't possible. It seems that the compiler overwrote your css stylesheet with it's output.

Comment: Would i have to retype all of the CSS then? would that be the best possible solution?

Comment: I think so, maybe you are in luck and have a duplicate stylesheet? It could be worth it to search in your pc if the css stylesheet was big. If it isn't so time consuming I would rewrite it. Maybe try to do it with sass, it is great!!